# Renaming files in folder with R

Tags: r, time-series

I have many files in my working directory with the same name followed by a number as such "name_#.csv". They each contain the same formatted time series data.

The file names are very long so when I import them into dataframes the df name is super long and I'd like to rename each as "df_#" so that I can then create another function to plot each individually or quickly plot,  for example, the first three without typing in this megalong name.

I don't want to concatenate anything to the current names, but take each one and rename it completely ending with the number in the list as it iterates through the files.

Here is an example I have so far.

```
name = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(name)) assign(paste0("df", name[i]), read.csv(name[i], skip = 15 ))
```

This is just adding a 'df' to the front and not changing the whole name.

I'm also not sure if it makes sense to proceed this way. Essentially my data is three replicates of time series data on the same sample and I eventually want to take three at a time and plot them on the same graph and so forth until the end of the files.

Comment: You assigning to an object in the global env with `assign` after reading the data.  You can check the `ls()` to see the object names.  Also,  the `name` from `list.files` include the `.csv` at the end as well.  If you want to modify the file name in the folder, use `file.rename`

Comment: @Ash Do you want to rename the file in the R global environment (i.e., import as `df_1`, `df_2`, etc, or rename the files in the actual folder?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I am hoping to do both.

Answer (score 0):

You can name the file in your global environment without renaming the original file in the folder by just telling R you want to assign it that name in the loop with a few modifications to your original code. For instance:

```
# Define file path to desired folder
file_path <- "Desktop/SO Example/" #example file path, though could eb working directory

# Your code to get CSV file names in the folder
name <- list.files(path = file_path, pattern="*.csv")

# Modify the loop to assign a new name
for(x in seq_along(name)){
  assign(paste0("df_", x), 
         read.csv(paste0(file_path, name[x]), skip = 15))
}
```

This will load the data as `df_1`, `df_2`, etc. I believe in your `assign` function you were using `paste0("df", name[i])`, which concatenates "df" with the filename in position `i`, not the value of `I` in the loop - that is why you were getting `df` prepended to each name on import.